# Laravel job can't find files in /tmp/ when running queue worker with supervisor

Tags: php, laravel, jobs, supervisord

I use laravel job & queue to defer some tasks in Laravel. What I'm going to do is store the uploaded files on the storage server and then do some processing on them. So I have defined two jobs and I run them in two queues.

The files are stored in the `/tmp/` path, but due to the use of **php-fpm** and **nginx**, this path is actually `/tmp/systemd-private-e8***2-php-fpm.service-3zCfIf/tmp/`

`Storage::disk('...')` is also used to access these files.
Everything works fine when I run the queue worker with the following command

```
php artisan queue: work database --queue = StoreMedia, ProcessMedia --sleep = 3 --tries = 5
```

The problem arises when I use **Supervisor**. In this case, the files are not found ... while they exist ... In this case, the path does not seem to be correct and `Storage::disk('...')->exist(...)` Returns the false value

The supervisor settings are as follows

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/app/artisan queue:work database --queue=StoreMedia,ProcessMedia --sleep=3 --tries=5
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile= /var/www/html/app/storage/logs/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

How should I use supervisor in this mode? Is Problem with supervisor access permissions to files? I think in this case the path is interpreted as `/tmp/x/.mp4` instead of `/tmp/systemd-private-e8***2-php-fpm.service-3zCfIf/tmp/x/y.mp4` And that has caused the problem. What is the solution?

Comment: Check the logs in `/var/www/html/app/storage/logs/worker.log` file and share them here.